# how to connect each port with sub domain in apache

Tags: node.js, apache, networking, port

I want to connect each sub domain with another port.

For example if I have example.com domain, I want to do like this

```
apple.example.com with 127.0.0.1:80 (Apache Port)
grape.example.com with 127.0.0.1:3000 (Node.JS App Port)
orange.example.com with 127.0.0.1:4000 (Another App Ports..)
```

I already create sub domains in my domain company and it works with 80 port. But it can not connect with another ports like 3000 or 4000.

What is the best way to solve this problem? When I search it on google some people said that I should use Virtual Host function in Apache, but someone said that it's not good way because of the performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. Here's the solution.

1. go to /etc/apache2/sites-available directory
2. Create file that has name your subdomain with conf (or domain) ex) test.example.com.conf
3. In conf file

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName test.example.com

       ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

In the 3000 for example put the port that I want to connect with.

4. Open the terminal and get root
5. type command `a2ensite Your_Domain`
6. Reload the apache2 with this command `systemctl reload apache2`

Finish, Sub domain(Or your domain) will work with inner port but external connect will show like 80 port.